# Resize Grid Items WinRt

Tags: xaml, gridview, windows-runtime

Can you resize grid items dynamically?

I have a gridview that has a textbox in it. They textbox has a number of bound values that can cause it to grow in size but it does not do so after the app is running.

```
    <Slider x:Name="FontSizeSlider" Minimum="10" Maximum="120" />

    <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" >
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock 
                    Height="{Binding ElementName=FontSizeSlider, Path=Value}"
                    Width="{Binding ElementName=FontSizeSlider, Path=Value}"
                    Text="{Binding}" 
                    FontSize="{Binding ElementName=FontSizeSlider, Path=Value}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

I realise that the items would have to shuffle around too so that then can fit in the columns. I don't think this is supported in gridview is it?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding:

```
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VariableSizedWrapGrid />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
```

Comment: Just found out this messes up the virtualisation of bound data... looking for a fix now.